# Trouble with While loop for a color guessing game

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, counter

Having difficulty with this assignment, here is the instructions we we're provided with.

create a program the user to guess your favorite color. **Using a while loop**, if the user didn’t guess your favorite color then tell them they are incorrect, then ask them again. Whenever they guess
the color correctly, output that they are correct and how many guesses it took them.

- Create a variable and assign it the value of 1
- Prompt the user to guess your favorite color
- While their guess is not equal to your favorite color:
- Tell them they are incorrect
- Prompt them to guess again
- Add one to the variable above
- Output to the user that they were correct and how many attempts it took, using the variable

Here is what I have so far **it doesn't work correctly**

```
correct_guess='red'
guess_count=0
guess_limit=float('inf')

while guess_count<guess_limit:
    guess = input('Guess a color: ')
    guess_count += 1

if guess == correct_guess:
    print('Congratulations! You won! it took you this many attempts: ' + str(guess_count))
    break
    
else:
    guess = input('Incorrect, guess again')
```

Comment: I see you have posted some code. Have you tried it? Does it do what you want? Are there any errors?

Comment: You need to move your check for a correct guess to *inside* the loop.  Think about what you're doing.  Do you want it to check for every guess?  Or do you want to discard all but the last guess, and then check only that guess, as you have now?

Comment: Unfortunately `" it doesn't work correctly"` is not a description of the symptoms. What doesn't work?

Comment: @quamrana sorry for not clearing it up, the program will correctly output the "correct_guess", but if the user enters a wrong answer(ex. "blue") it doesn't work properly and doesn't check any inputs after the first guess.

Answer (score 1):

With this code, your `if-else` statement is *outside* of the `while` loop. Since your loop runs forever, it will never exit the loop (so it won't run the rest of your code).
To fix this, try putting the code that is after the while loop inside, like so:

```py
while guess_count<guess_limit:
    guess = input('Guess a color: ')
    guess_count += 1

    if guess == correct_guess:
        print('Congratulations! You won! it took you this many attempts: ' + str(guess_count))
        break  
    else:
        guess = input('Incorrect, guess again')
```

Python is very indentation-based, so watch out for your indentation!

Also, next time you ask a question try to be a little more descriptive of your error/issue. Other people might not understand what is going wrong :)

**Edit:** You should also change the `guess = input('Incorrect, guess again)` to just a `print()` statement (you don't want the user to guess again there). Thanks to [@quamrana](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4834/quamrana) for this!

Comment: I tried switching things up as you mentioned, and it did clear a lot up. I still have 1 problem which is when the user inputs a wrong answer and is prompted to "guess again" it won't check that input for being correct and will instead loop back to "guess a color".  Also thanks for the advice, I'm new here.

Comment: Yes, I see. The code in this answer should be changed so that the `else:` clause just has: `print('Incorrect, guess again')`